# Re-entrance attack and run out of the gas, should revert the state?

Tags: reentrant-attacks

How the re-entrance attack (using .call) is able to change the state by using recursive call until it runs out of the gas (and it never reaches to the subsequent line to throw the exception).

I thought EVM will revert the state change if the transaction is running out the gas?

Answer (score 0):

you can send more gas with call than send and transfer which have a fixed limit of 2300, but even that isn't considered bulletproof protection anymore

https://consensys.net/diligence/blog/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/

Comment: if the answer helped you please upvote and accept